# How to apply a custom function to xarray.DataArray.coarsen.reduce()?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have a (2x2) NumPy array:

```py
ar = np.array([[2, 0],[3, 0]])
```

and the same one in the form of xarray.DataArray:

```py
da = xr.DataArray(ar, dims=['x', 'y'], coords=[[0, 1], [0, 1]])
```

I am trying to downsample the 2d array spatially using a custom function to find the mode (i.e., the most frequently occurring value):

```py
def find_mode(window):
    # find the mode over all axes 
    uniq = np.unique(window, return_counts=True)
    return uniq[0][np.argmax(uniq[1])]
```

The `find_mode()` works well for `ar` as `find_mode(ar)` gives `0`.

However, it doesn't work for `da` (i.e., `da.coarsen(x=2, y=2).reduce(find_mode)`), with an error:

```py
TypeError: find_mode() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature for functions passed to [`DatasetCoarsen.reduce`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.rolling.DatasetCoarsen.reduce.html) must include `axis` and `kwargs`. A good example is [`np.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html). So your function would need to look something like:

```py
def find_mode(window, axis=None, **kwargs):
    # find the mode over all axes 
    uniq = np.unique(window, return_counts=True)
    
    ret = uniq[0][np.argmax(uniq[1])]
    ret = np.atleast_2d(ret)

    return ret
```

Depending on your application, you may want to use the `axis` argument (tuple of integers) in place of your `[0]` and `[1]` indexing steps.

Note: I've added `np.atleast_2d` here to make sure the return array is 2D. This is a bit ugly so I recommend thinking a bit more about this part in your application. The key thing to understand is that the return array needs to have the same number of dimensions as the input array.

Comment: Thank you! I tried with your `find_mode()` and got another error: `ValueError: dimensions ('x', 'y') must have the same length as the number of data dimensions, ndim=0`. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Updated to note that the return shape needs to be the same as the input array.

Comment: It works as desired. Thank you!